# How to delay sending a transaction in brownie?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, brownie, timestamp

Say I have a contract that has a method that implements a time expiration via a function parameter set by the user, how can I test that the expiration works as expected in brownie by delaying the transmission and consequently execution of the transaction?

```
contract SimpleContract {

  function doSomething(uint256 exp) external {
    require(now < exp, 'Transaction Expired');
  }
}
```

```py
from brownie import SimpleContract, accounts
import time

def main():
  account = accounts[index]
  simpleContract = SimpleContract.deploy({'from': account})

  now = int(time.time())
  validFor = 20 # valid for 20 seconds
  simpleContract.doSomething(now + validFor, {'from': account})
```

Since brownie immediately submits the transaction by default it won't expire, so how do I get it to delay the submission and test that the transaction fails if its execution is attempted after the specified expiration time?

Answer (score 1):

You can [time travel](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-chain.html?highlight=time#time-travel) in brownie to push the timer forward.

```py
from brownie import chain
# some code here
print(chain.time())
chain.sleep(31337) # it's 31.3 seconds
print(chain.time())
```

This will shift the block timestamp in the blockchain.